# How to search for JIRA issues NOT in filter

Tags: jira, jql

How can I find issues which are not a member of an existing filter?

I have an agile board which naturally have a filter. Some issues within our project has been filtered from showing on this agile board and now I want a JQL search that can find all these issues, not visible within our agile board.

We have JIRA version 6.4.5.

Just to show what I have tried:

```
project = MyProj AND issueFunction in expression("", "filter != 1234")
```

.. and:

```
project = MyProj AND filter != 1234
```

.. which gives this error:

```
Field 'filter' with value '1234' matches filter 'MyProj' and causes a cyclical
reference, this query can not be executed and should be edited.
```

The content/JQL of filter `1234` is:

```
project = MyProj AND (component != "Special Work" OR component is EMPTY) ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

I do not have access to the REST API, if this is required.

Comment: What is the content of filter 1234?

Comment: @GlennV - hereby updated the description

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, this is a correct JQL query:

```
project = MyProj AND filter != 1234
```

But you probably saved the filter first, and I think you are now updating the JQL in your filter's search screen. In this screen you cannot refer to the same filter again because that is a cyclical reference. If you see the title of your filter in front of the Save button, then this is what's happening.

If you navigate to a clean search screen first, ie. click on "Issues --> Search for issues", then the above JQL should work fine.

Comment: You are right - if I start from a fresh JQL search then I am able to perform the search.

Comment: This is not working.